# how can i set default reset calls starting with api with out specifing the api in my reset url

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am implementing the reset services in my application. Is it possible to call  my reset calls starting with /api with out specifying the /api in my reset url mapping.

ex: my  reset url is like http://localhost:9080/DTHMS/defaultuser
but i want http://localhost:9080/DTHMS/api/defaultuser.

Note:I am using spring boot 2.0.2.

Comment: You can achieve this by using @RequestMapping annotation such as @RequestMapping("/api/defaultuser") before your implementation of service or @RequestMapping("/api") before your class.

Comment: By using this process I again rechange the  all resets call starting with /API. Is there any way to get rest calls starting with /API with out seting the /API in all my rest calls. I hered spring rest base-path feature in spring Boot is it useful to me to do this task. If it is  used to me can give a sample how to achieve this..! 
Thank you

Comment: Try this: define **server.contextPath=/API** in your application.properties.